# How to properly apply microtype footnote patch in an overleaf compiled document

Tags: formatting, overleaf, microtype

I am trying to compile a document. This is my preamble/main.tex file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % 11pt font


\usepackage[%
  colorlinks = true,
  citecolor  = blue,
  linkcolor  = blue,
  urlcolor   = blue,
  unicode,
  ]{hyperref}
% 1in margins
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

\singlespacing

\usepackage[tiny,compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\textsf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[%
  autocite     = plain,
  backend      = biber,
  doi          = true,
  url          = true,
  giveninits   = true,
  hyperref     = true,
  maxbibnames  = 99,
  maxcitenames = 99,
  sortcites    = true,
  style        = numeric,
  ]{biblatex}

\input{bibliography-mimosis}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}
```

Yet I get this warning

`1Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch` footnote' `

At the line where  `begin{document}` is written

How do I rectify this Warning message?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: tell microtype that it can't patch footnote: `\usepackage[final,nopatch=footnote]{microtype}`

Comment: you should always load the `hyperref` package as late as possible. In particular here, it must be loaded after `setspace`, which will otherwise overwrite hyperref's footnote definition.

Answer (score 0):

@Ulrike Fischer I used your suggestion

I told microtype that it can't patch footnote using this line

`\usepackage[final,nopatch=footnote]{microtype}`

Thanks